# How to do test automation a Qt3 Application

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, qt3

I need to automate GUI test of a qt3(3.3.3) Application.
Is  any test suits available to do it?

What I found so far is

1. LDTP
2. Dogtail
3. Squish

I tried LDTP and Dogtail both of them works with accessibility feature of qt which is enabled only on 4.8. The developer of LDTP said its easy to test if using Qt5 that Qt4.8 + some addition package and configuration.

I read squish supports qt3 but as its paid and I cannot afford it its not a choice.

I tried recompiling the source in a qt5 environment, but end up in missing header file errors.

eg: qpopupmenu.h No such file or directory

Comment: If you have the source code, consider porting your app to Qt4 or Qt5!